# Sending reminder by checking it everyday

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel. What I want to achieve is **I want a function that runs everyday automatically**. It will be **function that send emails to multiple receipients**. It will also checking whether it should send by certain condition. I look up internet and found about commands and task scheduler. However, it does not work. Nothing shows up(Error or email).

this is my command:

```
public function handle()
{ 
 $mail = User::where('id','=',$coordinator)->first();

 $data = [
        'name'     => $mail->name,
        'username' => $mail->staffid,
        'email'    => $mail->email
        ];                  

    Mail::send('email.AssignCoordinator', ["data1"=>$data], function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->from('testing@gmail.com', 'Testing');
            $message->to($data['email']);
            $message->subject('Test: Role Assign');
        });
}
```

this is my kernel.php:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('delay:mail')
                 ->everyMinute();
    }
```

**Note: I using everyminute() for testing**

Comment: "Nothing shows up(Error or email)." what do you mean by that?

Comment: I feel like that command not running because I don't get the email also no error

Comment: Where is `$coordinator` coming from? Have you set up the cron job for the scheduler?

Comment: i delete some of the codes because its too long. I don't quite understand cron job yet but I will check about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the scheduler by running `php artisan schedule:run` Or to set a cron :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Comment: isn't this `$schedule->command('delay:mail')->everyMinute();` consider running?

Comment: no you have to run schedule in a cronjob

Comment: I am so sorry Im such a newbie I cant find this cronjob...do I need to install it?

Comment: Cronjobs is a thing that runs your commands in a period. no need to run it if you are on a localhost,  just run the command `php artisan schedule:run`
Read the documentation and if it is working check this answer as accepted.